# oracle XMLType not working in database

Tags: java, oracle

in java i want to use oracle XMLType.
I add

```
XMLType type = new XMLType(conn, "<shipTo></shipTo>");
```

but i always get

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLParseException
```

why? i am using `xdb6.jar` for oracle 11 database. For connection i am using JDBC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the excerpt from my POM for doing the same (in JBoss):

```
  <!-- required for Oracle XML support -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
      <artifactId>xmlparserv2</artifactId>
      <version>11.2.0.1.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
      <artifactId>xdb</artifactId>
      <version>11.2.0.1.0</version>
  </dependency>
```

i.e. you need the XDB and XMLParserv libraries.

Comment: Thank you but i get Missing artifact com.oracle:xmlparserv2:jar:11.2.0.1.0

Comment: these libraries are not in any public repo. do you use your own repo?

Comment: Most likely. I can't remember where I got them from originally and would Google for them

Comment: thank you, works. It was not in local repo. I add it to nexus :D

Comment: After downloading the respective packages from Oracle, make sure you fetch the right `xmlparserv2.jar` and `xdb.jar` files, as it can be a wee bit [messy](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2539723) to the untrained eye.